# How to import npm package after React component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, gsap, react-component

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import '../brain/homePageLogic' // this import I needed after the component renders

function Home() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Hero>
        <h1>Hi, I'm Kartik</h1>
        <p>A web developer.</p>
      </Hero>
      <HeroSecondary className="hero-secondary" aria-hidden="true">
        <h1>Hi, I'm Kartik</h1>
        <p>A web developer.</p>
      </HeroSecondary>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Home.js

This is the main file where I need to implement my gsap logic

```
import gsap from 'gsap'
const hero = document.querySelector('.hero-secondary')
const tl = gsap.timeline({ delay: 1 })
.
.
.
.
.
```

homePageLogic.js

This is the gsap logic file where I would define what I will do with gsap.

But the problem is gsap logic file is imported statically in Home.js file even before the react Component renders causing error:

> Gsap target null not found.

Just wanted this gsap import to be done after the component renders.

Comment: Have you tried importing it dynamically in a useEffect hook?

Comment: @AndorPolgar can you tell me how to do so, like whats the syntax for importing in useEffect hook ?

Comment: Sorry, looking at your code again you don't need to import the whole thing dynamically, just put the DOM-dependent part into a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Comment: Oh I did it and its working fine now, thanks :)